# SQL Query optimization

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have some questions about my query. I call this store-procedure in my first page, so it is important for me if it is optimize enough.

I do some select with some basic `where` expression, Then I filter them with some expression I passed through this store-procedure.
It is also considerable for me to select `top n` and its gonna search through millions of items (but I have hundreds of items already) and then do some paging in my website.

```
Select top (@NumberOfRows) 
    ...     
from(
    SELECT  
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY tblEventOpen.TicketAt, tblEvent.EventName, tblEventDetail.TimeStart) as RowNumber
            , ...                    
    FROM    --[...some inner join logic...]
    WHERE     
            (tblEventOpen.isValid = 1) AND (tblEvent.isValid = 1) and 
            (tblCondition_ResellerDetail.ResellerID = 1) AND 
            (tblEventOpen.TicketAt >= GETDATE()) AND 
            (GETDATE() BETWEEN 
                            DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.StartTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt) 
                        AND DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.EndTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt))
) as t1
where RowNumber >= (@PageNumber -1) * @NumberOfRows and 
    (@city='' or @city is null or city like @city) and 
    (@At is null or @At=At) and 
    (@TimeStartInMinute=-1 or @TimeStartInMinute=TimeStartInMinute) and
    (@EventName='' or EventName like @EventName) and
    (@CategoryID=-1 or @CategoryID = CategoryID) and
    (@EventID is null or @EventID = EventID) and
    (@DetailID is null or @DetailID = DetailID)
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

1. I'm worry about this part:

   `(GETDATE() BETWEEN 
                               DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.StartTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt) 
                           AND DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.EndTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt))`
   How does table `t1` execute? I mean after I put some `where` expression after t1 (line 17 and further), does it filter items after execution of t1? for example I filter result by rownumber of 10, so it mean the inner `(...) as t1` select will only return 10 items, or it select all items then my outer select will take 10 of them?
2. <del>I want to filter my result by some optional parameters, so I put something like `@DetailID is null or @DetailID = DetailID`, is it a good way?</del>
3. <del>Anything else should I consider to make it faster (more optimize)?</del>

Comment: It's not so easy to see which are the large tables here. Have you looked at the query optimization plan. Are you getting lots of index seeks or index scans? You should be aiming at index seeks. One suggestion for 1. above is to work out the to and from dates before the query and store them in variables.

Comment: I'm learning, I did't read any query optimization plan, if you may provide me one :). I'm currently not using any index plans. My biggest table here is `tblEventOpen`, but I don't think it help. For my first problem, thanks, I will use @today variable instead of GetDate()

Comment: you need to run the EXPLAIN command before the query to get information about the indexes the database decides on the index, so when you say you are not using any index plans, that's not something you do, the database engine does it!  When you use EXPLAIN you will get results from the database about what indexes it IS using to help you decide if you need to create a different one based  on the query criteria.

Comment: @Leslie: It's T-SQL, which doesn't have `EXPLAIN` statement, I suppose.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` doesn't work as Andriy said, or maybe I should put it somewhere special?!

Answer (score 2):

My comment on your query:

1. You're correct, you should worry about condition "`GETDATE() BETWEEN ...`". Comparing value with function involving more than 1 table will most likely scan entire search space. Simplify your condition or if possible add a computed column for such function
2. Put all conditions except "`RowNumber >= ...`" in inner query
3. Its okay to put optional condition the way you do. I do it too :-)
4. Make sure you have index at least one for each column employed in the where clause as the first column of the index, and then the primary key. It would be better if your primary key is clustered

Well, these are based on my own experience. It may or may be not applicable to your situation.

[UPDATE] Here's  the complete query

```
Select top (@NumberOfRows)
    ...    
from(
    SELECT  
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY tblEventOpen.TicketAt, tblEvent.EventName, tblEventDetail.TimeStart) as RowNumber
            , ...                    
    FROM    --[...some inner join logic...]
    WHERE    
            (tblEventOpen.isValid = 1) AND (tblEvent.isValid = 1) and
            (tblCondition_ResellerDetail.ResellerID = 1) AND
            (tblEventOpen.TicketAt >= GETDATE()) AND
            (GETDATE() BETWEEN
                            DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.StartTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt)
                        AND DATEADD(minute, (tblEventDetail.TimeStart - 60 * tblCondition_ResellerDetail.EndTime) , tblEventOpen.TicketAt)) and
            (@city='' or @city is null or city like @city) and
            (@At is null or @At=At) and
            (@TimeStartInMinute=-1 or @TimeStartInMinute=TimeStartInMinute) and
            (@EventName='' or EventName like @EventName) and
            (@CategoryID=-1 or @CategoryID = CategoryID) and
            (@EventID is null or @EventID = EventID) and
            (@DetailID is null or @DetailID = DetailID)
) as t1
where RowNumber >= (@PageNumber -1) * @NumberOfRows
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was waiting for complete answer( sorry for my delay). so is number 2 necessary? is it help my query run faster?

Comment: I'm afraid I did't catch what you mean by your `4th` solution. And is it necessary to bring my where clause into my inner query? I have to notice you that I can write this store with only one single query!! but It will decrease readability and code maintaining. So All I have to ask is my first question. please read my comments on another given answer by @Chris. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can seek advice on your query, it is better to learn how to optimise it yourself.

You need to view the execution plan, identify the bottlenecks and then see if there is anything that can be done to make an improvement.

In SSMS you can click "Query" ---> "Include Actual Execution Plan" before you run your query. (Ctrl+M) is they keyboard shortcut.

Then execute your query. SSMS will create a new tab in the results pane. Which will show you how the SQL engine executes your query, you can hover over each node for more information. The `cost %` will be particularly interesting, allowing you to see the most expensive part of your query.

It's difficult to advise you any more without that execution plan, which is why a number of people commented on your question. Your schema and indexes change how the query is executed, so it's not something that someone can accuratly replicate in their own environment without scripts for tables / indexes etc.... Even then statistics could be out of date and other problems could arise.

You can also execute `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` to get a textual view of the plan (maybe useful to seek help).

There are a number of articles that can help you fix the bottlenecks, or post another question for more advice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx

[SQL Server Query Plan Analysis](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx)

[Execution Plan Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

Comment: +1 for (Ctrl+M). I think `Set statistics profile on` is kind of useless because I did't get anything about analyzing my query, It is full of estimated values (and `totalsubtreecost` which I think might be useful if it tell me how much time does it spend on subquery), or maybe it is beyond my knowledge to take advantage of it. I did't bring schema or index information because I did't want to focus on this particular query. As a mater of the fact I just want to show how I personally write my stores and if there is something wrong with this kind of writing...

Comment: my main question was my `first` question, that is, if I have `select * from (BIG_QUERY_WITH_WHERE) where store_filters_goes_here` should I really concern about outer where expression and place it IN my `BIG_QUERY_WITH_WHERE`? And I need some kind of prof if you it is possible :D